# How to divide the rectangle into $5$ parts?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

I have a rectangle of width  $20$ meters, length $50$ meters.

> How to draw the divider inside this rectangle into $5$ parts, each part has an area of $​​200m^2$ provided that the total length of the drawn lines inside the rectangle be divided as short as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try to optimize this shape.  It should be slightly shorter than 80m
[image]

A second option is to use circular arcs that meet at angles of $120^\circ$, and cut the edge at right angles.  It gives a total length around 78.25m
[image]

Comment: Looks about 1.2m shorter.

Comment: Great; it seems your shape $2$ is optimal solution; my calculations show total length $78.2644...$ m.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw
4 lines of length 20
separated 10 apart.

Don't know how to prove
that this is the best.

Note that after
three of these have been drawn,
what is left is a 20 x 20 square,
so the last line can be
vertical or horizontal.

This might imply that
other arrangements
might be better.
However,
I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest length between tow lines(opposite side of rectangle) is when the drawn line between them is perpendicular to the sides. You have to draw four such lines to divide the area in five parts The total shortest is $4 \times 20=80 m$

Comment: But the OP does not specify that the parts are rectangular.